# session storage retain value after refresh

Tags: angularjs

Actually i got a value in sessionStorage but it will not inject in page. When we refresh the whole page that time it will inject.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
ctrl.modelObject = $sessionStorage.associatedCspaList;
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="cspa in ctrl.modelObject track by $index">{{cspa}}</li>
</ul>

associatedCspaList:["1111111111111111","1111222233334444","1111222244445555","1231123112311231","1234567891234567","1234567893216549"]
```

Comment: Did you console.log the value? It can be that your html will render before the value will be set.

Comment: After console.log it will shown me previous value instead of current value.

Comment: And how you set the sessionstorage?

Comment: Using below code i set the sessionStorage

`$sessionStorage.associatedCspaList = responseData.data.associatedCspaList;`

Comment: Thats not how you set session storage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Tried but not working for me.